# How to extract unicode value of an NSString

Tags: unicode, nsstring

I'm trying to extract the unicode value of the first character of an NSString for range checking purposes. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString.characterAtIndex(index)` is the method you're looking for

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:

Comment: For prosperity, extracted it to a unicode char...
        unichar checkKana = [self.kanji characterAtIndex:i ];